# How to add a Configmap to a specific Pod In a StatefulSet?

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

I'd like to know how I can add a ConfigMap to a specific pod spawned by a StatefulSet.

I've looked at the spec and I can't figure out how to ensure that a pod only mounts a ConfigMap with a specific label.
I've already got a workaround ready in the form of a container. However I'd still like to know if this is possible out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't treat a pod inside the same StatefulSet as a special pod. Simply because you can only specify a single `PodSpec` that's valid for the whole set.

A workaround is to mount all versions of the config files in every pod and run an entrypoint script that uses different config files based on the pod name. I have no example to show but it should be quite easy

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to know if it was possible. I already have a workaround. I'm using an initContainer to funnel data from the ConfigMaps into the PersistentVolume that's created for each pod.
The container checks the current hostname and checks a sepecific directory for paths that contain the current hostname. If so it copies the file into the PersistentVolume.
It's ugly, and I'll move away from it later. For now it works.

Comment: I found this issue and it's exactly what I am looking for... Is it possible to have a specific configMap for each pod in the statefullset? Or is the only option using the mention workaround? Thanks

Comment: The answer still applies

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution, based on Mutating Webhook, is available https://github.com/spoditor/spoditor to solve this exact problem.

Essentially, it uses a custom annotation on the `PodSpec` template, like:

```
      annotations:
        spoditor.io/mount-volume: |
          {
            "volumes": [
              {
                "name": "my-volume",
                "secret": {
                  "secretName": "my-secret"
                }
              }
            ],
            "containers": [
              {
                "name": "nginx",
                "volumeMounts": [
                  {
                    "name": "my-volume",
                    "mountPath": "/etc/secrets/my-volume"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
```

Now, `nginx` container in each Pod of the StatefulSet will try to mount its own dedicated secret in the pattern of `my-secret-{pod ordinal}`.

You will just need to make sure `my-secret-0`, `my-secret-1`, so on and so forth exists in the same namespace of the StatefulSet.

There're more advanced usage of the annotation in the documentation of the project.