# configMap entry from pod information

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I am checking how to use statefullset on kubernet to deploy my service.
In stateFullSet, I able to know the pods names because it would be always the stateFullSet name + a sequence number like:

```
app-0
app-1
app-2
```

so I would like to have a specific configuration in configMap for each pod and the pod would reading the config map based on the pod hostname.

It would be something like:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: cgwcontainer
      image: helioay/nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /opt/app/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: "pod_host_name"
```

I have seen that I can get the pod hostname based on the POD information "metadata.name" , but I am not sure if I am able to use this information as configMap name value.
I know it is possible to set environment variables like:

```
      env:
        - name: NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Is it possible to use similar solution but for the configMap name?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384602/how-to-add-a-configmap-to-a-specific-pod-in-a-statefulset) might be useful, let me know if that help You.

Comment: Thanks @jt97... from the link you commented, seems it´s not possible to do what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You need to be a more specific and provide more details.